# Gmail Attachment using gmail API

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to download attachment using Gmail API and below is the code for the that

```
var Data = req.body;
var parts = Data.payload.parts;

for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
var part = parts[i];
if (part.filename && part.filename.length > 0) {
  var attachId = part.body.attachmentId;
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
    'id': attachId,
    'messageId': message.id,
    'userId': userId
  });
  request.execute(function(attachment) {
    callback(part.filename, part.mimeType, attachment);
  });
}
}
```

I have used the link 
[Gmail API to get the Attachment](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get) and since it require autorization as mention so who to pass the refershToken,clientSecret,clientId,accessToken etc..or whether this is required first place.

Currently i am getting Gmail is not defined, i have installed gapi and included it as

```
var cs = require("coffee-script/register");
var gapi = require('gapi');`
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used gapi inside of nodejs environment, but from my experience in using gapi library in chrome extensions - after loading gapi script you need to load gmail separatelly - something like this:

```
gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', callback);
```

And after that you can start using it. That's probably reason for getting "Gmail is not defined" error.
Additionally, you can always make API calls without using gapi library.